Simplest way to test whether a Vector3 point is inside a game object in Unity 3D
My purpose is to approximate an irregular, non-convex collider with a set of box colliders. In order to do this I want to write a bool IsPointInside(Vector3 point) function that test if point is inside the object which the script is attached to.
The complication is that the object mesh can't be approximated using a single box, sphere, cylinder or custom convex mesh.
I've tried to implement it via Raycast:
public bool IsPointInside(Vector3 point)
{

    // Cast rays in multiple directions to increase reliability
    Vector3[] directions = { Vector3.up, Vector3.down, Vector3.left, Vector3.right, Vector3.forward, Vector3.back };
    int hitCount = 0;

    foreach (var direction in directions)
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(point, direction);
        RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, Mathf.Infinity);

        foreach (RaycastHit hit in hits)
        {
            if (hit.collider == meshCollider)
            {
                hitCount++;
            }
        }
    }

    // If the average number of hits per direction is odd, the point is inside
    return (hitCount / directions.Length) % 2 != 0;
}

The problem is that this implementation, as well as being very underperforming, seems to not work properly since some of the points I expect to be outside the mesh return true, while some points I expect to be inside return false. For now I'm not interested in time efficiency since I'm running the script outside the game.
The question is: is there another simpler approach to address this problem? What's the state of the art for my goal?
Any help, both theoretical and practical, is appreciated.
I attach the picture of the object just to let you have an idea.


Use Physics.CheckSphere with a small radius?

The approach looks correct to me, and is the typical approach for "contains", except that a single direction should be sufficient. I believe your problem can be seen in the documentation for raycast:

Notes: Raycasts will not detect colliders for which the raycast origin is inside the collider.

Unfortunately I'm not very knowledgeable about Unity. Perhaps do all raycasts from outside the mesh, and ignore any hits closer to the origin than the point you really want to check?
The approach I have used in other software has been to do ray-triangle intersection myself. See for example this article.
Also note that your meshes need to be "well formed", i.e. lack any holes. Otherwise there will not be a well defined "inside" and "outside".
If you want to "voxelize" your mesh you could also compute the intersection of the mesh with a set of planes. I.e. split it into discrete layers. And then rasterize the resulting polygons for each layer, probably by using some drawing library to draw them to an image.

A single raycast in Unity can only hit a single collider once. To get around this, you can do another raycast from the collision point and continue from there.
You also will need to set Physics.queriesHitBackfaces to ensure that the raycast will hit the inside of the mesh collider.
public bool IsPointInside(Vector3 point)
{
    // Change "queriesHitBackfaces" to true
    bool previousBackfaceSetting = Physics.queriesHitBackfaces;
    Physics.queriesHitBackfaces = true;

    // Arbitrary direction to shoot in.
    Vector3 shootDirection = Vector3.up;
    
    int meshHits = 0;

    // Stop raycasting if we didn't hit anything.
    // TODO: use collision layers to improve this.
    while (Physics.Raycast(point, shootDirection, out RaycastHit hit))
    {
        // We did hit something, if we hit our collider then increment.
        if (hit.collider == meshCollider)
        {
            meshHits++;
        }

        // Update the new raycast origin
        point = hit.point;
    }
    
    // Restore old "queriesHitBackfaces"
    Physics.queriesHitBackfaces = previousBackfaceSetting;

    // If the number of hits per direction is odd, the point is inside
    return hitCount % 2 != 0;
}

Note: the code is untested, you might need a slight adjustment to the point along the shootDirection if it keeps hitting the same point over and over. I don't think this should happen? But it might.

The points outside are returning true because this is what your code is doing: you are making a raycast from outside the box colliders in any direction until you "meet" any of those boxes.
This is how I would proceed. First I would try to use the Mesh Collider instead of hundreds of boxes:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html
Then, you can set the mesh collider as Trigger and then use an OnTriggerEnter function on the "player" to check whether you enter your mesh.
To improve performances, I would evaluate to split the mesh in many submeshes. You could also have a unique mesh for visualization (to avoid rendering problems), and many subparts just for the mesh colliders.
